# Correct breadcrumbs structure for the dropdown navigation

Tags: navigation, menu, drop-down-list, breadcrumbs

Situation - navigation menu that contains both single links and dropdown.
I used colors as an example (in the real product these are not colors).

I'm designing breadcrumbs, and the tricky part is, that sometimes page name is different than the menu link (user clicks link "Yellow", but the name of the page is "Dark yellow"); sometimes it's the same (Grey - Grey). Considering this, it looks like option B is better - saying "Grey - Grey" feels a little bit strange. Blue is not a page itself.

But from the other hand it would be great to start breadcrumbs with navigation link, even if it wont be clickable - because for the dropdown items it would be good to have name of the parent link.

**Any suggestions, which approach is better in this situation?**
Maybe you can provide any examples?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Option A - keeping navigation link in breadcrumbs structure]

[image: Option B - removing navigation link from the breadcrumbs]

Comment: is this really for colors, or just an example? If this is for colors, I think the proper taxonomy to use is Colors, then you wouldn't have any issues, because the breadcrumb would be *Colors / Grey* or *Colors / Blue / Turquoise* (I'd argue the need for blue being a category, but even then, it will work). Now, if the elements are variable and have different taxonomies thei it's a different story

Comment: Would "yellow" be its own page, and "dark yellow" be a separate page, then each would have its own "details" page? I guess I am a bit confused about the overall goal here. 

Have you created a sitemap or navigation map to identify all the different paths that you would take?

Comment: Breadcrumbs always should show the page name, not some category name. Are those really breacrumbs? If they are [have a look at this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/132730/36883).

Comment: @Devin , I just edited main question - no, in the real product these are not colors, sorry for not specifying this in advance.

Comment: @smuxer , "Yellow" links to the "Dark yellow", "Gray" -> "Gray", and "Blue" is empty. So there is no need for these to have details page. "Dark yellow" in this situation is not "Yellow" just because the real name is very long, and it would be impossible to keep such long page name in the navigation. We just used mental shortcut in the main navigation, and then "real" and long name as the page name.

Comment: If you can't select 'Yellow' as its own page, then why would it be included in the breadcrumb navigation?

Comment: @smuxer Just as the path information - it will be path-based breadcrumbs ("history trail"). So for the dropdown items it makes sense I guess, user clicked category "Blue" and picked item "Azure", so he is now in the  "Blue > Azure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way - I've included category as part of the page title.
Thank you all for your insights.
[image: Option C - adding category to the page title]